# Showing animations through page scrolling

Tags: javascript, css, animation, scroll, delay

So I've been trying to follow this tutorial http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/getting-animations-trigger-right-time and realised those effects only work for elements that contain images. I wanted to get this effect on elements that don't contain images (i.e: a block of text) but couldn't make it work. Does anyone have any idea on how to achieve this? Thank you guys!

Here's the script:

```
<script>
 if (Modernizr.csstransitions) {
    function preloadImages(imgs, callback) {
     var cache = [],
       imgsTotal = imgs.length,
       imgsLoaded = 0;

       $(imgs).each(function (i, img) {
         var cacheImage = document.createElement('img');
              cacheImage.onload = function () {
              if (++imgsLoaded == imgsTotal) callback();
                                                };
               cacheImage.src = $(img).attr('src');
               cache.push(cacheImage);
                                        });
                                };
                                $.fn.trans = function () {
                                        var t = arguments[0],
                                                d = arguments[1] || '';
                                        if (t) {
                                                $.each(this, function (i, e) {
                                                        $(['-webkit-', '-moz-', '-o-', '-ms-', '']).each(function (i, p) {
                                                                $(e).css(p + 'transition' + d, t);
                                                        });
                                                });
                                        }
                                };

                                document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="animations.css" />');

                                $(function(){
                                        //preload images contained within elements that need to animate
                                        preloadImages($('.services img, .featured img'), function () {
                                                $('.services, .featured').appear({
                                                        once: true,
                                                        forEachVisible: function (i, e) {
                                                                $(e).data('delay', i);
                                                        },
                                                        appear: function () {
                                                                var delay = 150,
                                                                        stagger = 800,
                                                                        sequential_delay = stagger * parseInt($(this).data('delay')) || 0;

                                                                $(this).children().each(function (i, e) {
                                                                        $(e).trans(i * delay + sequential_delay + 'ms', '-delay');
                                                                });
                                                                $(this).removeClass('animationBegin');
                                                        }
                                                });
                                        });
                                });
                        }
                </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find Lightweight jQuery scrolling script that handles viewport css3 animations **[SEE HERE](https://github.com/davidhalford/DivPeek)**

I have created one demo which show how it works, scroll the fiddle and you will see the animation when element is in viewport.

**[SEE THE DEMO HERE](http://goo.gl/gqUuEu)**

Comment: Great stuff thanks a lot. But is there any way to achieve the same thing changing my code above? The main reason is because with my example elements inside the same div will animate one by one without placing an extra attribute individually. Hope this makes sense.  Thanks ;)

Comment: you can use delay to animate css animation one by one in my code only.